Prove that $\forall x,y\in E:\gcd(\pi_{x},\pi_{y})=1 \implies \pi_{x}\pi_y=\pi_{x+y}$.

$E$ is a $\mathbb{K}-$vector space. let $f$ be an endomorphism of $E$. $\forall x \in E$,  note $I_{x}=\{ P \in \mathbb{K}[X]:P(f)(x)=0 \}$. Since $I_{x}$ is an ideal then there exists $\pi_{x}$ a non constant monic polynomial such that $I_{x}=\pi_{x}\mathbb{K}[X]$. Prove that $\forall x,y\in E:\gcd(\pi_{x},\pi_{y})=1 \implies \pi_{x}\pi_y=\pi_{x+y}$.

Since $\gcd(\pi_{x},\pi_{y})=1$ then $\exists  U,V \in \mathbb{K}[X]:U\pi_{x}+V\pi_{y}=1$. Using this we can prove that $(x,y)$ is linearly independant. Another point we can prove is that $\pi_{x}\pi_{y}\mathbb{K}[X] \subset \pi_{x+y} \mathbb{K}[X]$. However this is all my argument plan stops at, I don't see how we can push this further.

To continue your proof after already showing linear independence,
$pi_x$ annihilates $x$ and $pi_y$ annihilates $y$, hence it follows that $pi_x 
, pi_y$ annihilates both $x$ and $y$, and hence $x+y$. Therefore, $ \pi_x \pi_y \in I_{x+y} $, which implies $ \pi_x \pi_y \mathbb{K}[X] \subseteq \pi_{x+y} \mathbb{K}[X] $.
To show $ \pi_x \pi_y = \pi_{x+y} $, you it is needed to prove the reverse inclusion $ \pi_{x+y} K[X] \subseteq \pi_x \pi_y \mathbb{K}[X] $. Since $ \gcd(\pi_x, \pi_y) = 1 ,  \pi_x $ and $ \pi_y $ have no common factors. This implies that any polynomial that annihilates both $x$ and $y$ must be a multiple of $ \pi_x \pi_y $. Any polynomial in $ \pi_{x+y} \mathbb{K}[X] $ must also be in $ \pi_x \pi_y \mathbb{K}[X] $. Given that $ \pi_x $ and $ \pi_y $ are coprime, their product $\pi_x \pi_y $ is the minimal polynomial that annihilates both  $x$ and $y$, and hence $ x+y $. Therefore, $ \pi_{x+y} $ must divide $ \pi_x \pi_y $, completing the reverse inclusion.

Since $I_{x+y}={ P \in \mathbb{K}[X]:P(f)(x)+ P(f)(y)=0 }$, wouldn't it possible to choose a certain a certain polynomial $P$ that doesnt necessarly annihilated $x$ and $y$, where $P(f)(x)=-P(f)(y)$? I noticed that in your reverse inclusion proof you've mentionned that necessarly $\forall P \in I_{x+y}:P \in I_{x} \cap I_{y}$ so I wonder why. Thanks in advance.

I meant an example of a polynomial that satisfies $P(f)(x) = -P(f)(y)$ but doesn't necessarily annihilate x and y would be $P(f) = f(x) - f(y)$. This polynomial gives opposite values at x and y for any function f, but it doesn't necessarily equal zero at either point.
